# Logstash not listening on UDP port 5140

Tags: centos, udp, logstash, listen

I am running a logstash shipper, rsyslog sends logs to logstash on port 5140, I can confirm the packets are arriving with:

```
tcpdump -vvv -A -i any port 5140
```

I have logstash configured like so:

```
input {
  udp {
    type => "syslog"
    port => 5140
  }
}

filter { }

output { 

  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }

  redis {
  host => "172.30.114.151"
  key => "logstash"
  port => "6379"
  data_type => "list"
  }
}
```

I have also tried the following on for the input:

```
input {
  syslog {
    port => 5140
  }
}
```

Which netstat shows tcp Listen but not udp.

I have disabled ipv6 for logstash with the following flag:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

When I run:

```
netstat -tulpan
```

I get:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1191/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2135/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7593/rsyslogd       
tcp        0      0 172.26.33.182:22        172.30.230.152:47975    ESTABLISHED 2260/sshd: 
tcp        0      0 172.26.33.182:22        172.30.230.151:42811    ESTABLISHED 6781/sshd: 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1191/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::4440                 :::*                    LISTEN      1296/java           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      2135/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::514                  :::*                    LISTEN      7593/rsyslogd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5140            0.0.0.0:*                           8499/java           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37934           0.0.0.0:*                           653/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           653/avahi-daemon: r
```

Process 8499 is logstash. I have tried running as root and as well as other ports. I cannot seem to get logstash to "listen" on udp

I have also confirmed that the port is open and working with:

```
telnet <ipaddress> 5140
```

Selinux is disabled:

```
 sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

I need some help with this. I have searched and searched. I have looked into every other solution I have come across with no luck. This may seem like a duplicate. However, the other solutions are not working for me. This is a centos installation. Have also tried ports 514, 10514 to no avail.

Comment: I copied everything to another machine and it worked perfectly. My conclusion is that it had something to do with the OS

Comment: I don't see how your `telnet` is able to confirmed that the port is open when `telnet` is not in udp protocol, but a tcp protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow the port in firewall as centos comes up with default firewall which doesn't allow traffic to get to logstash input

Allow traffic on a specific port by following command:

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2888/tcp`

disable firewall or stop service with following command:

```
systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
```

**Disabling firewall can be a security concern but for experimental purposes you can give it a try